# Assign or copy?

Tags: objective-c, reference, assign

This is a method inside my `Rectangle` class. A `Rectangle` object has an `ivar` called `origin` from the class `XYPoint`. An `XYPoint` object has an `ivar` of `float x` and `float y`. Is this method okay for setting the `origin` or will it be referencing the same spot in memory as `pointy`?

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *) pointy {
    origin.x = pointy.x;
    origin.y = pointy.y;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be okay because you're passing floats, not objects. By default passing a float passes the value - not the memory location - unless you put an `&` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is perfectly okay, as you are assigning values not a pointer. :)